# About the relationship between the GUID and the Contact Key in Salesforce Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am using the Salesforce Marketing Cloud’s MobilePush SDK. I understand that a GUID value generated at initialization is later replaced with a contact key using the setProfileId or setContactKey method. I have a few questions regarding this process.

When the GUID value is replaced with a contact key using setProfileId or setContactKey, what information is it linked to for this replacement?

Is the setContactKey value replaced in association with the GUID value generated at initialization? If so, what information is the GUID format based on? (Device ID or other system identifiers, etc.)

I am particularly interested in this because I have noticed that the device ID seems to change with each app installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the GUID value is replaced with a contact key using setProfileId
> or setContactKey, what information is it linked to for this
> replacement?
>
> Is the setContactKey value replaced in association with the GUID value
> generated at initialization? If so, what information is the GUID
> format based on? (Device ID or other system identifiers, etc.)

Already answered by Bill here: [How to configure right contact key for MobilePush - Marketing cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404315/how-to-configure-right-contact-key-for-mobilepush-marketing-cloud)

> I am particularly interested in this because I have noticed that the
> device ID seems to change with each app installation.

**That's normal, there are a few other scenarios in which the Device ID can change, for example:**

- The Device ID will not persist an uninstallation/re-installation of the application: a new Device ID will be generated.
- The Device ID will not persist a consumer’s clearing of application data.
- The Device ID will not persist a consumer’s factory reset of their device.
- The Device ID will not persist when restoring from a backup.

**Scenarios that will not result in a new DeviceID:**

- The Device ID will persist through platform upgrades (version x of OS -> version y of OS).
- The Device ID will persist through SDK updates unless expressly called out in the release notes.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393339&type=1

Comment: Thank you, Rachid Mamai, for sharing valuable information and detailed explanations. I appreciate your expertise and experience. Looking forward to more interactions.